# Make Google Chrome report it's running on a different OS

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent, chromium

I'm running Chrome on Linux and I want to make it report to the website I'm developing as it's running on a Windows machine and on a Mac OS, for testing purposes. I'm not talking just about the User Agent, if you go to `about:version` there is a field which says `OS:`. I want to fool the website as much as I can, how is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure if you can do this, but I'd start with looking at Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) and then intercepting the calls and modifying the relevant fields.

Comment: Looks interesting, even if it can't do what I asked, this post was already worth it. Thanks :)